# json and jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

I want get data from php with jquery.I wrote this code:

```
<?php 
      $return=array('content'=>1,'id'=>2,'priority'=>3);
      echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

in jquery:

```
$.ajax({
 type:'post',
 url:'next_prev.php',
 data:{act:act,id:id,priority:priority},
 dataType: 'json',
 cache: false,

 success:function(data){
 var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data)
 $('#content').html(obj.content);
 $('#priority').html(obj.priority);
 $('#id').html(obj.id);

 },
 });
```

but it does not work.whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: i think you have to use var in success function like - obj[content]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data in the success callback is formatted according to dataType, i.e. no need to parseJSON it again

try to remove `var obj=jQuery.parseJSON(data)` and use `data.content` `data.priority` etc directly

Comment: I have a html in php page when delete html it work.thanks alot